# Binding char colmn for SQL Server

Tags: data-binding, odbc

ALL,

My search with Google didn't produce anything and the example in MSDN does not cover it so....

In my table I have a column with a type `char(1)`. I am trying to retrieve it with the following binding:

```
SQLWCHAR dataFontItalic[2];
SQLLEN cbDataFontItalic = SQL_NTS;
ret = SQLBindCol( stmt_tableProp, 6, SQL_C_BIT, &dataFontItalic, 2, &cbDataFontItalic );
```

Unfortunately this code does not work. I don't see the value under the debugger. And unfortunately SQLGetDiagRec() does not say which field in the query is troublesome but I presume it is the first one and the error I'm getting is

```
Invalid character value for cast specification
```

The value in the column is 'N'.

Does anybody can spot the issue?

---

EDIT:

Defining dataFontItalic as SQLCHAR didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Apparently I need to bind to SQL_C_CHAR and not to SQL_C_BIT.

Hopefully this will save someone else's time.